# High memory consumption on Azure Function App on Linux plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I just switched from Windows plan to Linux on Azure Function App and memory usage went up 5 times.

I didn't change the way how package is built. And it is just `dotnet publish -c Release --no-build --no-restore`. I wonder if I could do sotmething here - build for specific runtime?

Is there a way to decrease that consumption? I'm wondering because my plan was to switch all functions to Linux plans as they are cheaper, but not neceserilly if it ends up in higher plans.

Few details:

- dotnet 3.1
- function runtime version ~3
- functions run in-process

[image]

The function is rarely used, so there is no correlation between higher memory usage and bigger traffic.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I experienced nothing but troubles when switching to Azure Functions running Linux. My .NET 6 AZs deployed from a Mac did not even work at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check if my findings are helpful**:

**Memory Working Set** is the Current amount of memory used by the Function App in MB's or the tracking how much of the application is currently loaded in physical memory.

If the requests are high, then the Memory working set is most likely to increase.

AFAIK, during the initial start/request or cold start of the Azure Function takes high memory consumption ranges nearly 60 MiB - 180 MiB and the net memory working set count depends on the amount of physical memory is using by our function application during requests and response time.

[image]

According to [Azure Functions Plan Migration Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#plan-migration), direct migration to a Dedicated (App Service) plan in not supported currently and this migration is not supported on Linux.

Also, you can check the cause and resolution on Azure Functions (Linux Plan) > `Diagnose and Solve Problems` > `Availability & Performance` >

[image]

Comment: I added more details in the question. I know that there is no direct migration. Thus I deleted function and created a new on Linux plan. Since metric relies on resource id I have them on single chart.

Comment: Hello @KrzysztofMadej, could you please go through `Diagnose and solve problems` blade to find the root cause of high memory consumption from `Availability and performance` option and let me know what it shown!

Comment: I don't use consumption plan, so diagnostics section here will not help me.

Comment: Could you confirm that your using dedicated App Service Linux Plan or Premium? to check by re-deploying my function app in it!

Comment: I use `App Service Linux Plan` P1V3